# Python API to generate geometry vertices?

Tags: python, opengl, vertices

I've been trying to find a python API that is able to generate geometry vertexes all day. Basically I have a PyOpenGl application that uses OpenGL 3.3 and I need to be able to draw cubes, spheres, torus and cones. I'm frustrated after roughly 10 hours researching and failing over and over again; haven't been able to either find a library that generates this for me, or create a function my self. The closest I got is a API called `pyrr` that has a function to generate vertexes for a cube with `pyrr.geometry.create_cube(scale=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), st=False, rgba=False, dtype='float32', type='triangles')` but thats it. OpenGL fixed function had functions to draw spheres and toruses so why is it that hard to find an API that has a function something like this: `create_sphere(0.5)` that would return the vertexes of a sphere centered at (0,0,0) with radius 0.5 ordered in such way that they can be drawn using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`? Does anyone know any python API that have such functions?

Comment: OpenGL never had any functions to create geometry. If you mean [`glutSolidSphere`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node81.html), they are from glut, not OpenGL.

Comment: @BDL That is what I meant, but still the function exists